# Is there any way to return connection to Hikari pool even if the service method is not completed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions, hikaricp

```
public void completeOrder(OrderRequest request) { 
    generateOrder(request); // DB call
    generateInvoice(request); // DB call
    paymentApi(request); // external API call
    savePaymentInfo(request); // DB call
    createSubscription(request) // DB call
    sendInvoiceEmail() // internal API call
}
```

In the above code snippet:

1. The Connection is opened and it starts generating the orders until all the code snippet of the completeOrder method is executed.
2. If there is any delay in the payment API, the connection is on hold and it is not returned to the connection pool.
3. If we have concurrent users doing complete orders, the application is running out of Database Connections resulting in the application lag.

I went through a blog which is trying to resolve the issue with the help of TransactionTemplate ( https://medium.com/javarevisited/transaction-management-in-spring-boot-eb01e20b21fe ) but not working for me.

If i see logs for below code I get *HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)* even if saveTestDto(testDto) is executed. Is there anything i need to do extra or do we have some other technique to resolve such issues.

```
@Service("testService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{

    @Autowired
    TestRepository testRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void testMethod(TestDto testDto) throws InterruptedException {

        template.execute(
                status -> {
                    saveTestDto(testDto);
                    return testDto;
                }
        );

        this.sleep();

        template.execute(
            status -> {
                updateTestDto(testDto);
                log.info("Object updated.");
                return testDto;
            }
        );
    }

    private void saveTestDto(TestDto testDto){
        testRepository.saveAndFlush(testDto);
        log.info("Object saved.");
    }

    private void updateTestDto(TestDto testDto){
        testDto.setInfo("This is test 1");
        testRepository.saveAndFlush(testDto);
        log.info("Object saved.");
    }

    private void sleep() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make sure you don’t have calls to transaction manager wrapped into another transaction. If you are using spring boot chances are each rest request is wrapped into transaction due to OSIV

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view#:%7E:text=Introducing%20Open%20Session%20in%20View&text=Spring%20opens%20a%20new%20Hibernate,same%20interceptor%20closes%20that%20Session.) you can find out more about Spring Open Session in View